# Pass variable from one html file to another

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm creating an Angular 2 webpage - I originally had 1 HTML file that contained everything I needed for my web page's UI - for design reasons, I've taken out a part of the HTML and created a separate component for it (specifically a Tree view display). I've been able to reference the other HTML file (treeview) fine using its selector `tree-selector` in my original HTML like so:

```
<div *ngIf="showTree">
    <h1>Using treeview template.</h1>
    <tree-selector></tree-selector>
</div>
```

The code for tree-selector.html is (I'm using PrimeNG UI components):

```
<p-tree [value]="fileSystemTree" selectionMode="single"  (onNodeSelect)="nodeSelect($event)" (onNodeUnselect)="nodeUnselect($event)" (onNodeExpand)="nodeExpand($event)" [style]="{'max-height':'200px','overflow':'auto'}"></p-tree>
```

Before, when everything was in 1 file, it was easy to use the variable `"fileSystemTree"` to use for `[value]`. Now that I have two HTML files, I'm unsure of how to use `fileSystemTree` again in my main HTML and link it to `[value]` in tree-selector.html.

Comment: You'll have to pass any data you want to retain in the GET string with the request, and then parse it with javascript on the other page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it to `<tree-selector></tree-selector>` as input parameter and then further to `<p-tree...>`

```
<div *ngIf="showTree">
    <h1>Using treeview template.</h1>
    <tree-selector [fileSystemTree]="fileSystemTree"></tree-selector>
</div>
```

in tree-selector component:

```
@Input() fileSystemTree: any;
```